# Getting a filesize in a batch file where the filename is known

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filesize

I'm trying to write a simple batch file that allows me to compare two filesizes, where both filenames are already known and set within the batch file itself.

But just getting one filesize is proving difficult. Here is the smallest piece of code that replicates the problem:

```
IF EXIST "flava.jpg" (

  REM Get current filesize 
  FOR /F %%A in ("flava.jpg") DO SET _existingFileSize=%%~zA

  ECHO %_existingFileSize%

) ELSE (

  ECHO File not found.

)
```

From what I've read [here](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), it should echo the variable's contents. What's going on?

Comment: Please show the code in-context. I believe that you probably have this `for` and the following `echo` within a `code block` (a parenthesised series of statements) - please edit your question to include the entire code-block (from the initiating `for` or `if` to the finl closing `)`

Comment: @Magoo Rather than overwhelm, I've put up the smallest bit of code that still replicates the issue I'm having. (Tested on my machine, and still having the same problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF EXIST "flava.jpg" (
  REM Get current filesize 
  FOR /F %%A in ("flava.jpg") DO SET _existingFileSize=%%~zA
  ECHO !_existingFileSize!
) ELSE (
  ECHO File not found.
)
```

or

```
IF EXIST "flava.jpg" (
  REM Get current filesize 
  FOR /F %%A in ("flava.jpg") DO SET _existingFileSize=%%~zA
  CALL ECHO %%_existingFileSize%%
) ELSE (
  ECHO File not found.
)
```

or

```
set "_existingfilesize="
FOR /F %%A in ("flava.jpg") DO SET _existingFileSize=%%~zA
if defined _existingfilesize (echo %_existingfilesize%) else (echo file not found)
```

The issue is that within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

Comment: Fantastic educational answer! Enough information for me to solve this problem myself. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to print a filesize of one or more files. I made a *subroutine* making it easier to write complex code blocks. If you need two named files use exact *file* values.

```
@echo off
set file=*.bat
for %%A in (%file%) do call :DOIT %%A
goto :END

:DOIT
echo %1 size is %~z1
goto :EOF

:END
pause
```

Comment: There's no need for the subroutine. You can just to `%%~zA` instead.

Comment: @Joey Could you explain further? Thanks. I really can't see what's wrong with my code :(